# How to authenticate MS graph requests?

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, postman

I am using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer to make requests

I am trying to convert them to Python to use for general automation.

I always copy from browser>postman>code, so I have all the cookies/tokens/etc. I need, and my python request will work until something expires. In this case, that something is a bearer token.

I can’t figure out how to get a new, **valid** bearer token other than re-doing above process or copying just the token and copy-pasting into my code.

While trying to find an auth request that would spit one out, I came across a collection for Postman here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

and when I replace {{tenant}} with my orgs tenant_id, I get a 200 request with *a* bearer token, but when I insert this bearer token into my Graph API request code I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.","innerError":{"date":"2022-10-23T14:31:22","request-id":"...","client-request-id":"..."}}}
```

Here is a screenshot of the Postman Auth

[image]

Here is my Graph API call that only works with bearer tokens copied from graph-explorer

```
def recreate_graph_request1(bearer = None):
  '''
  I went to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
  and picked a request. Outlook>GET emails from a user
  at first response was for some generic user, but I logged in using my account and it actually worked.
  Then I used my old copy curl as bash trick to make it python

  :return:
  '''
  url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=(from/emailAddress/address)%20eq%20%27my.boss@company.com%27"

  payload = {}
  headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Authorization': bearer,
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Origin': 'https://developer.microsoft.com',
    'Referer': 'https://developer.microsoft.com/',
    'SdkVersion': 'GraphExplorer/4.0, graph-js/3.0.2 (featureUsage=6)',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'client-request-id': 'n0t_th3_s4m3_4s_1n_P05tm4n',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"'
  }

  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

  return response

token_from_ms_auth = 'eyCOPIED_FROM_POSTMAN....'
bearer_from_ms_auth = 'Bearer '+token_from_ms_auth
print(recreate_graph_request1(bearer_from_ms_auth).text)
```

TBH, I was not overly optimistic that any bearer token would work, even if it was somehow associated with my tenant - but I hoped it would, and the resulting disappointment has driven me to ask the universe for help. I do not understand these meandering flows and looking at others' answers only confuses me more. I am hoping someone can help me figure out this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access tokens are short lived. Refresh them after they expire to continue accessing resources.

[image]

Please refer this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up figuring how to do that by re-purposing a request in MS provided collection to look like a refresh request in MS docs, but which is not provided in postman collection. This actually worked and is an improvement- but this refresh token is itself only good for 1 day

Comment: I am using that same POST request as the one in your docs

Comment: Refresh tokens have a longer lifetime than access tokens. The default lifetime for the refresh tokens is 24 hours for single page apps and 90 days for all other scenarios:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens#refresh-token-lifetime